# Secure Module across multiple controllers

Tags: java, playframework

Using Play 1.2.3 I am trying to implement the Secure Module across multiple controllers.

I have added `- play -> secure` to my dependencies and the secure module appears in my project. I have imported the default secure routes `* / module:secure`, customised the authenitcation method and annotated all of my controllers using the `@With(Secure.class)`.

The problem that I am having is that when I move between controllers I receive a `Null Pointer Exception` thrown from the `secure:module` at line 193: `return Java.invokeStaticOrParent(security, m, args);`

<s>A second issue that I am having is that when methods are called from within the same controller, some calls can take up to 20 seconds to complete where they would normally be instant without the secure module included.</s> **Edit: this was unrelated - the secure module has no visible effect on loading time**

My question is has anyone else implemented the secure module in Play across multiple controllers, and if so, did they come across any of these issues?

#### Edit

*The problem was down to the use of a tag in my template - not in the implementation of the secure module. See below for reason and how to resolve.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the null pointer exception was being thrown was because in my template I was calling:

```
#{secure.check}
    <li><a href="@{Secure.logout()}">Logout</a></li>
#{/secure.check}
```

I had oddly thought this was a template tag to check whether there was security enabled - but it actually needs be followed by a 'profile' type - which is not something I specified nor have implemented (hence the exception).

To get around this, I added a basic template tag that checks whether the security associated session is in use:

```
#{if session.username}
    #{doBody /}
#{/if}
```

And can simply implement as follows:

```
#{secure.secure}
    <li><a href="@{Secure.logout()}">Logout</a></li>
#{/secure.secure}
```